# An odd function $f$ is differentiable at zero. Prove $f'(0)=0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know that $f'$ of an even function is odd function, thus I have $f(x)=f(-x)$.
However I'd no idea how to prove that $f'(0)=0$?
Please answer my question...

Comment: Your title says $f$ is odd.  In the post you say $f'$ of an even function.  So, is the function odd or even?

Comment: How about $f(x)=x$?

Comment: The odd function $\sin x$ is differentiable at $0$, its derivative is not $0$ at $0$. Do you mean an even function is differentiable at $0$, show the derivative is $0$ at $0$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas He said the function is even. $\sin x$ is odd.

Comment: The title says odd function.

Answer (score 5):

You have $f(x) = f(-x)$. Then, we can take derivative on both sides, and use chain rule:
$$
[f(x)]' = [f(-x)]' \quad\Longrightarrow\quad 
[f(x)]' = [-x]'f'(-x) \quad\Longrightarrow\quad 
f'(x) = -f'(-x)
$$

If $x=0$ we have: 
$$
f'(0) = -f'(0) \quad\Longrightarrow\quad 
f'(0) + f'(0) = 0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad 
2f'(0) = 0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad 
f'(0) = 0
$$

QED.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean that $f(x)$ is an even function. If so, note that for an even function $f(x)$,  it satisfies $f(x)=f(-x)$. Now if a function is differentiable, it satisfies

$$f'(x) =\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Now note that
$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(-h)-f(0)}{-h}$$$$=-\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=-f'(0)$$

So we have $f'(0)=-f'(0)\implies f'(0)=0$